# Enable direct share in Samsung S7

Tags: share-menu

I had OPT and the direct share option is a great feature.
However it looks like it's missing on my Galaxy S7.
Is there any way of enabling it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Settings > Advanced Features > Direct share